# iOS How to update data use UISegmentedControl with parse Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have one big issues, i want to update data in data base, and use the UISegmentedControl. When i want to change status, i get the error.

> Fatal error: Index out of range

My code to update the data:

```
@IBAction func processSegmentControllTapped(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "requests")
    let currReceipt = self.data[sender.tag]
    query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: currReceipt.objectId!)
    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in
        if error != nil {
            self.alert(message: "We could not delete the receipt", title: "Oops! Something went wrong number 1!")
        }
        else {
            for object in objects! {
                print ("index: ", sender.selectedSegmentIndex)

                if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
                    object["status1"] = 0
                }

                if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
                    object["status1"] = 1
                }
                if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
                    object["status1"] = 2
                }
                object.saveInBackground(block: { (success, error) in })
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Do you have multiple `UISegmentedControl`? And do those segmentedControl have their own tag number? If so, check if the element exists in `self.data` Array at the index of `sender.tag`. If not, it is natural that you'll get such error message.

Comment: No i have only one UISegmentedControl

Comment: Why do you set the tag of segmentedControl? I think if you have only one segmentedControl, you don’t have to set the tag number.

Comment: Anyway, I think the error occurred at `let currReceipt = self.data[sender.tag]`. So, Check if the value of `sender.tag` is grater than the last index of `self.data[sender.tag]`.